# How can I make my custom data types to work with a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

The following error

[image]

```
The type 'DataTypeNamespace.DoubleDataType' cannot be used as type parameter 
'T' in the generic type or method 'DataTypeList<T>'. There is no implicit 
reference conversion from 'DataTypeNamespace.DoubleDataType' to 
'DataTypeNamespace.IDataType<DataTypeNamespace.DoubleDataType>'.
```

is shown up in the following source code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataTypeNamespace
{
    public interface IDataType<T>
    {
        T Data { get; set; }
        T Add(T other); 
    }

    class IntegerDataType : IDataType<int>
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }

        public int Add(int other)
        {
            return Data + other;
        }
    }

    class DoubleDataType : IDataType<double>
    {
        public double Data { get; set; }

        public double Add(double other)
        {
            return Data + other;
        }
    }
    public interface IDataTypeList<T> where T : IDataType<T>, new()
    {
        T Sum();
    }
    public class DataTypeList<T> : IDataTypeList<T> where T : IDataType<T>, new()
    {
        List<T> collection;
        public T Sum()
        {
            T sum = new T();

            foreach (T item in collection)
            {
                sum = sum.Add(item);
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoubleDataType double1 = new DoubleDataType();
            double1.Data = 10.5;

            DoubleDataType double2 = new DoubleDataType();
            double2.Data = 20.5;

            DataTypeList<DoubleDataType> dataTypeList = new DataTypeList<DoubleDataType>();
            DoubleDataType sum2 = dataTypeList.Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make my custom data types to work with a generic class?

Comment: `class DoubleDataType : IDataType<double>,IDataType<DoubleDataType>` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incongruent. Let's take a look step by step.

You define `IntegerDataType` as `IDataType<int>`, so its `Add` function would return an integer.
Now, you restrict `DataTypeList<T>` to accept only `IDataType<T>`, so per example you would use `IntegerDataType`.
But now, inside the `Sum` function of `DataTypeList<T>` you do:

```
T sum = new T();

foreach (T item in collection)
{
    sum = sum.Add(item);
}
```

Do you see the problem? `Add` will return an `int`, but `T` is `IntegerDataType`, something totally different.

To solve this, you would change the definition of your interface and data class to something like this:

```
public interface IDataType<T>
{
    T Data { get; set; }
    IDataType<T> Add(IDataType<T> other);
}

class IntegerDataType : IDataType<int>
{
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public IDataType<int> Add(IDataType<int> other)
    {
        return new IntegerDataType { Data = Data + other.Data };
    }
}
```

The problem now lies in the restriction of `T` in `DataTypeList<T>`.  If `T` is `IntegerDataType` then you are restricting the parameter to be `IDataType<IntegerDataType>` which is not what you want.  You want it to be `IDataType<int>`, which can't be achieved with only one generic parameter type.

You can, of course, add a second generic parameter and then declare `DataTypeList<IntegerDataType, int>` but it's ugly and I think it defeats what you're trying to achieve.

The best you can do is to split your `IDataType` in two: a base interface and a generic one. The base one will declare the `Add` function but its return type will be of the type of this base interface, and the generic interface will inherit from that base interface and declare the `Data` of type `T`. In this way, you can restrict in `DataTypeList` `T` to be of the base type achieving your goal. Something like this:

```
public interface IDataTypeBase
{
    IDataTypeBase Add(IDataTypeBase other);
}

public interface IDataType<T> : IDataTypeBase
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}

class IntegerDataType : IDataType<int>
{
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public IDataTypeBase Add(IDataTypeBase other)
    {
        var cast = other as IntegerDataType;
        return new IntegerDataType { Data = this.Data + cast.Data };
    }
}

public interface IDataTypeList<T> where T : IDataTypeBase, new()
{
    T Sum();
}
public class DataTypeList<T> : IDataTypeList<T>  where T : IDataTypeBase, new()
{
    List<T> collection;
    public T Sum()
    {
        T sum = new T();

        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            sum = (T)sum.Add(item);  //IDataTypeBase can be cast to IntegerDataType
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntegerDataType int1 = new IntegerDataType();
        int1.Data = 10;

        IntegerDataType int2 = new IntegerDataType();
        int2.Data = 20;

        DataTypeList<IntegerDataType> dataTypeList = new DataTypeList<IntegerDataType>();
        IntegerDataType sum2 = dataTypeList.Sum();
    }
}
```

I assume your code is a **scraped** example which has a lot of functionality missing as `int1` and `int2` are never added to the list that you `Sum`.

Comment: `IDataTypeList<T>` seems to be unused here.

Comment: @user366312 Added to the declaration of `DataTypeList<T>` but it's useless (also it was in your implementation).

Comment: @user366312 Not totally sure, I think the incongruence of the `T` restriction.